# being able to confirm if a table is being used in sql server

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Is there a way to confirm 100% if someone is using this table?
[image]

I get the below numbers… 63 user_scans would indicate some activity…
[image]

But there is a daily job doing this, so I think the 63 comes from there…

…

```
DELETE KeyMetricHistory 
        WHERE MonitorDate BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE

        WHILE @STARTDATE <= @ENDDATE 
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO KeyMetricHistory (MonitorDate,country,members,leads,freetrial,revenueOS,closewon,revenueTS)
            exec ET_Report.dbo.[rpt_DailyMonitorReport] @STARTDATE

            SET @STARTDATE = DATEADD(DAY,1,@STARTDATE)
```

…

If those 63 user_scans are not part of this job, how can I know if they are not part of another job or scheduled activity; or how can I know if those 69 were done next to creation date like (January 2014)

Comment: Rename the table and await users reporting errors?

Answer (score 0):

From your question i understood that you want to know where that particular table is using in any object and If you really want to know whether that particular table is using in any object like view,procedure,view,function and to know the object name , this is the query .Ignore this query if your need is not what i understood

```
 select
    object_name(m.object_id) as OBJECT_NME, m.*
from
    sys.sql_modules m
where
    m.definition like N'%KeyMetricHistory%'
```